# How to specify an empty string as Target null value in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

From here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx,

It gives an example of specifying 'TargetNullValue':

```
<TextBox Width="150"
         Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource object2}, 
  Path=PropertyB, BindingGroupName=bindingGroup, 
  TargetNullValue=please enter a string}" />
```

My question is how can I specify an empty string for TargetNullValue?

I have tried `"TargetNullValue= }"` (there is a space between = and }, but that does not work, the target null value is null, instead of an empty string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `x:Static` in the xaml and define the string.empty there.

```
<TextBox Width="150"
         Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource object2}, 
  Path=PropertyB, BindingGroupName=bindingGroup, 
  TargetNullValue={x:Static system:String.Empty} }" />
```

You'll need to add the appropriate namespace to the xaml as needed. VS should do this for you though. Namespace required is

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: I am getting 'Unknown type 'Static' in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml''

Comment: I have added 'xmlns:system="using:System" in the namespace

Comment: I tried copy and paste your namespace declaration, and then change to  <TextBlock Text="{x:Static system:String.Empty}" > But I still get the same compiler error:  XamlCompiler error WMC0001: Unknown type 'Static' in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/x

Comment: @n179911 you can't use the `Text` property of the `Textbox` like that without the Binding . Try copying the entire thing in my answer.. its your code i modified so it should just work.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know why the answer saying to use `''` is deleted, but it works fine for me:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NumberOfCats, TargetNullValue=''}" />
```

Comment: Works for me too, and is a lot easier to use.